# What IPS monitor should I buy?

Tags: display, lcd

My eyes are pretty sensitive and get strained easily.
I am in the market for a new monitor that will be used for programming, browsing the web and watching movies and playing an occasional game.

I've heard good things about IPS monitors.

I narrowed down my search to the following 2 monitors:

```
NEC EA231WMi 
Dell 2209WA
```

They are roughly around the same price.
Which would better suit my needs?
Is either of them better quality?

Thanks!

Comment: My dice picked Dell...

Comment: I've always had very good results with NEC equipment.  I'm not a fan of Dell anymore, so I'll vote "NEC".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't worry at all about the type of monitor - if you have sensitive eyes, you will most likely have problems on anything looking at white.

If you need a new monitor, I would personally always go for the cheapest that matches the specification you need (no point in paying extra just for one port that you will never use!) and then look at using alternate colour schemes that will be a lot easier on your eyes.

[image]

Comment: Well i'd also like the monitor to be nice to look at, the cheaper monitors tend to look bad during watching movies and viewing images...

Comment: There are only a few companies that actually make the panels, (I think for the good ones, it is just three on last count)... It is likely that whoever you use, you will get the same panel anyway - which is why I recommend just going for the cheapest that has what you need (Including style if that is your choice), but the quality of picture will most likely be the same on anything within the same range/price.

Comment: Both of these panel have IPS panels which are different from most of the other panels in the same price range namely TN.